# using multiple return statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, return

I am trying to use multiple returns but just keep breaking the code. I have tried a few examples, but cant find the right combination.

How can I combine these two return statements into one?

```
$(".bar").popover({
content: 
    function (){
        return $(this).data('dataObj').status;
        return $(this).data('dataObj').timeline;
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `popover` content attribute require a string?

Comment: just use return `$(this).data('dataObj')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
function (){
    return $(this).data('dataObj');
}
```

OR

```
function (){
    // return an array
    return [ $(this).data('dataObj').status, $(this).data('dataObj').timeline ]
}
```

OR

```
function (){
    // return a associative array
    return { "status": $(this).data('dataObj').status, "timeline": $(this).data('dataObj').timeline }
}
```

And process the components in the caller.

**Update**

The `content` parameter for `popover` needs a string as argument, you can do this:

```
function (){
    return $(this).data('dataObj').status + " " + $(this).data('dataObj').timeline;
}
```

Comment: -1 Who knows how much data is inside `dataObj` - there is no reason to return the whole object if you only need two of it's properties.

Comment: By your logic why not simply return the entire `data()` object.

Comment: I've removed my vote because you've added some better suggestions, but my comment still stands...

Comment: Returning `dataObj` is probably better. It's an already allocated object. It's *already* consuming memory. Creating a new array or object to return only certain values takes *more* memory. The only scenario where it would make sense to do that is when `dataObj` is very big and has no other references pointing to it.

Answer (score 4):

Putting aside this specific case, where the plugin demands a certain type of return value (apparently a string in this case), you can't really... **A return statement terminates the function**. What you'll have to do is return an object (or an array) containing those two values -

```
var status = $(this).data('dataObj').status;
var timeline = $(this).data('dataObj').timeline;
return [status,timeline];
```

Or

```
var status = $(this).data('dataObj').status;
var timeline = $(this).data('dataObj').timeline;
var returnObj = {'status':status, 'timeline':timeline};
return returnObj;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return objext ir array containig those two items

```
$(".bar").popover({
content: 
    function (){
        return 
        {
        status: $(this).data('dataObj').status;
        timeline: $(this).data('dataObj').timeline;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. But I want to understand the role that plays these colons in status: and timeline:, it seems to be case statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning an array with .status and .timeline as elements.
Ok Lix was faster.